# React, my prop always returns true as soon as it's conditioned

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a `props`, when it is `console.log` alone it returns me `true` or `false`correctly.

As soon as I test this same `props` with `props ? true: false` it always returns `true` even if the value is `false`.

I do not know where to look, any idea or suggestion ?

```
    render(){
        return (
        div
           {console.log(this.props.model.isActive} // return true or false correctly (boolean)
           {console.log(this.props.model.isActive ? 'trued' : 'falsed')} // return always trued even if false
        /div>
     );
    }
```

EDIT :
my props return a `string`, not a `boolean`..... :@

Comment: `console.log(props)` returns `"true"` or `true`. Make sure `props` is `boolean` not `string`

Comment: @Prakashsharma yes it returns really `boolean`

Comment: @Prakashsharma after verification, you're right, props return a `string`, not a `boolean`..... thx a lot !